# Same address, multiple shared_ptr counters, is it forbidden by C++ standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, language-lawyer

Suppose I have the need to do the following (This is just some imaginative code for discussion of the C++ standard, thus I won't discuss why I design it this way, so don't bother me with something like: your design is wrong.)

```
T* ptr = new T;
shared_ptr<T> p(ptr);
shared_ptr<T> q(ptr, SomeDeleterThatDoesnotDeleteButDoSomeOtherStuff());
```

Suppose the logic guarantees that `p` or some of its copies lives longer than all copies of `q`, so practically there won't be any problem.  My question is, is it forbidden by C++ standard, e.g. explicitly stated as UB by C++ standard, for different shared_ptr counters to share the same address?

Thanks.

Comment: What if you `return q;`?

Comment: @Peter I think that's the idea — to invoke the non-deleter and do something useful with the knowledge that some subset of references is now empty.

Comment: The design isn't *that* terrible for its purpose. You could guarantee proper destruction by replacing the custom deleter with one that *does* delete, and also owns its own `shared_ptr` 1. to a dummy object that performs the action in its destructor or 2. having another custom deleter that performs the action. But those methods could be less efficient, if the set(s) of `q` objects changes rapidly relative to the set of proper owners `p`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, you got it.  This is actually exactly what I did in my actual work: let the non-deleter owns the `p`.

Comment: @icando But... when `p` goes out of scope it will delete `ptr`, and the returned `q` will point to an invalid object, with no way of knowing. This seems like a really bad idea. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @PeterWood, please read my questions, please.  I've already said logic guarantees `p` or some of its copies lives longer than all copies of `q`.  I've also said I am not welcome on the criticism of the design itself.  In previous comments I've already said letting `q`'s deleter hold a copy of `p` can achieve this guarantee, which is the implementation detail I thought not interesting to talk about so didn't put in the question.  Therefore the situation you insisted in your comment will never happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find anything in the standard (well, the final draft) that specifically rules it out. The closest I can find is a note in `20.9.11.2.10 shared_ptr casts`

> 5 [ Note: The seemingly equivalent expression
>   shared_ptr(static_cast(r.get())) will eventually result in
>   undefined behavior, attempting to delete the same object twice. —end
>   note ]

which actually seems to forget about your case with a custom deleter.

Answer (score 5):

If the first shared_ptr object is destroyed, then you get UB because objects using the second might access released object.

Since you made sure that your first shared_ptr object lives longer then the second, you do not get UB.