# Same address, multiple "shared_ptr"s, enable_shared_from_this & custom deleter

Tags: boost, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

Related to [Same address, multiple shared_ptr counters, is it forbidden by C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079770/same-address-multiple-shared-ptr-counters-is-it-forbidden-by-c-standard) and myriad other questions around multiple shared_ptr objects pointing to the same object but not sharing the underlying ref count structure.

What happens if the object inherits from "enable_shared_from_this" in the above mentioned question?  What does my shared_from_this() return?  One with the custom deleter or the one without?

```
struct B : boost::enable_shared_from_this<B> {
  boost::weak_ptr < B > get_weak() {
    return shared_from_this();
  }
};

void doNothing(B *) {
}

int main() {
  B * b0 = new B;

  boost::shared_ptr < B > sddb0(b0, doNothing);
  boost::weak_ptr < B > swddb0(sddb0->get_weak());
  //  Does this have a custom deleter???
  boost::shared_ptr < B > sddb1 = swddb0.lock();

  boost::shared_ptr < B > scdb0(b0);
  boost::weak_ptr < B > swcdb0(sddb0->get_weak());
  //  Does this *not* have a custom deleter???
  boost::shared_ptr < B > scdb1 = swcdb0.lock();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deleter is associated with the owned object and will be used to dispose of it when the last owner drops its reference, so all pointers that share ownership of the same object also share the deleter.  The deleter is not stored in individual `shared_ptr` objects, it's stored on the heap along with the reference counts, so shared by all the objects that share the same counts.

So let's looks at your code. First, I had to fix your code as it didn't even compile as shown. It's always a good idea to test the code in your question, to avoid wasting people's time by making them fix typos and add missing headers.

Don't write this:

```
B * b0 = new B;

boost::shared_ptr < B > sddb0(b0, doNothing);
```

The correct way to do that is:

```
boost::shared_ptr < B > sddb0(new B, doNothing);
```

The `enable_shared_from_this<B>` base has a `weak_ptr<B>` member which gets assigned to by the `shared_ptr` constructor, so that `weak_ptr` shares ownership with `sddb0`, as does the shared pointer returned by `shared_from_this()`.

So the answer to this question is yes:

```
//  Does this have a custom deleter???
boost::shared_ptr < B > sddb1 = swddb0.lock();
```

`sddb1` shares ownership with `sddb0` so has the same deleter.

You could test that by  using `get_deleter`, or by writing to `stdout` in `doNothing`, or by using `owner_less` to compare the owners of the pointers.

This creates an object that does *not* share ownership with the existing shared pointers:

boost::shared_ptr < B > scdb0(b0);

The `enable_shared_from_this<B>` base's `weak_ptr<B>` member gets re-assigned to by the line above, so it shares ownership with `scdb0` instead of `sddb0`. So when you call `get_weak` after that point it returns a weak pointer that shares ownership with `scdb0` and so doesn't have a custom deleter. Again, you can easily verify that by seeing that `doNothing` isn't called, or by using `owner_less`.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer this.  I went through the boost code for enable_shared_from_this and it reassigns the weak pointer, but I assume we should treat this as an implementation detail and not rely on it.